# Ubuntu touchpad issues (works on Live USB but not on installation)

Tags: touchpad

I've installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my lenovo flex 5. While using the live USB the touchpad worked just fine. After installation, it didn't...

It didn't show up on `xinput`.

What to do now?

Comment: I am experiencing the same on my Lenovo Flex 5 with 20.04 and kernel 5.15. It worked well initially also, but no longer. Not detected with `xinput`.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

This worked for me.

Comment: Hi there, please provide some context as to why you think this would be useful for this particular problem. Some links to documentation would be great.